# How to control startup options of dnsmasq?

Tags: networking, 16.04, network-manager, dns, dnsmasq

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial and Network Manager started `dnsmasq` for me with these options:

```
~/ ps awux|grep dnsmasq
nobody    2649  0.0  0.0  54488  3588 ?        S    Mai23   0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --cache-size=0 --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
```

I'd like `dnsmasq` to read/use the `/etc/hosts` file as well, which it currently doesn't seem to, because of the option **`--no-hosts`**.

How do I change the startup options, that Network Manager uses to invoke dnsmasq?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure NetworkManager's dnsmasq to use /etc/hosts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117899/configure-networkmanagers-dnsmasq-to-use-etc-hosts) with resolution [added here](http://askubuntu.com/a/628870/16747)

Comment: @krondor Thanks, this did do the trick: `echo 'addn-hosts=/etc/hosts' | sudo tee /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/etc-hosts && sudo service network-manager restart`

Answer (score 0):

All `dnsmasq` configuration files you add into `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/` are passed to `dnsmasq`. Just check it with the command:

```
ps -ef | grep -P "dnsmasq\s"
```

I get this kind of result (notice the `--conf-dir` parameter):

```
nobody    6105  5868  0 20:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --cache-size=0 --clear-on-reload --conf-file=/dev/null --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
```

So you could just create a file e.g. `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/my-hosts` containing the declaration:

```
addn-hosts=/etc/hosts
```

in order to use `/etc/hosts` (see [doc](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dnsmasq)).
But because `dnsmasq` starts also with `--no-hosts` this might determine `dnsmasq` to still ignore `/etc/hosts` so you could just create a hard link to it e.g.:

```
sudo cp -al /etc/hosts /etc/my-hosts
```

then change the declaration to:

```
addn-hosts=/etc/my-hosts
```