# Troubleshooting dnsmasq

Tags: 16.04, dns, dnsmasq

I'm having DNS issues on a new install of Ubuntu 16.04:

```
kqs@mycomputer:~$ nslookup localserver
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

** server can't find localserver: NXDOMAIN
```

But if I specify the DNS server (or sometimes if I just wait awhile), it works:

```
kqs@mycomputer:~$ nslookup localserver 192.168.0.1
Server:     192.168.0.1
Address:    192.168.0.1#53

Name:   localserver.localdomain
Address: 192.168.0.24
```

And this is the same DNS server that shows up first in Network Manager:

```
kqs@mycomputer:~$ nmcli device show
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:     192.168.0.152/24
IP4.GATEWAY:        192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:       dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:         192.168.0.1
IP4.DNS[2]:         131.215.254.100
IP4.DNS[3]:         131.215.139.100
```

It seems to be the same problem as "[dnsmasq sometimes resolves things, sometimes it doesn't](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131342/dnsmasq-sometimes-resolves-things-sometimes-it-doesnt)" and "[Intranet address resolution and dnsmasq](https://askubuntu.com/questions/850966/intranet-address-resolution-and-dnsmasq)", but in that solution they disable `dnsmasq` by commenting out the `dns=dnsmasq` line in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`.

However, I'd like to troubleshoot `dnsmasq` rather than bypassing it completely.

So my questions are:

1. My understanding is that `dnsmasq` is a lightweight DNS server running on my computer. Presumably, the Network Manager DNS settings are used to configure `dnsmasq`, but ultimately it is `dnsmasq` that is solely responsible for handling DNS lookups (with the help of upstream DNS servers as it deems necessary). Is this correct?
2. Can I see how `dnsmasq` is handling a particular DNS lookup? i.e. is it answering it from its cache? Which upstream DNS server is it forwarding it to?
3. Can I instruct `dnsmasq` to use a particular DNS server for the local domain?

Answer (score 3):

#### 1. `dnsmasq` and Network Manager

As yourself from a few days in the future: your understanding is correct.

Note, however, that Network Manager launches an instance of `dnsmasq` as a child process (not a separate daemon) and keeps its own set of dnsmasq configuration settings.

#### 2. Can I see how `dnsmasq` is handling a particular DNS lookup?

Sorry, I still don't know.

#### 3. Can I instruct `dnsmasq` to use a particular DNS server for the local domain?

Yes, the `--server` option in `dnsmasq` ([manpage here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/dnsmasq.8.html)) allows you to specify upstream DNS servers for specific domains.

You can pass this option to Network Manager's invocation of `dnsmasq`. I did this by creating a file in the directory `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/` with the contents:

```
server=//192.168.0.1
```

Normally, this line would be `server=/domain/<ipaddr>`; in this case the empty domain specification means "unqualified names only", such as `localserver` in your example (as opposed to `localserver.domain`).

#### How I fixed your immediate problem

The above change still didn't fix things. I verified that this was loaded (`service NetworkManager status` shows a log entry `dnsmasq[<pid>]: using nameserver 192.168.0.1#53 for unqualified names`), but it still returns `NXDOMAIN` on lookups. So I settled on the following hack:

The local machines I'm connecting to all have static IPs, so I manually specified these in a file in `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d` with the contents:

```
address=/localserver/192.168.0.13
address=/localserve2/192.168.0.14
[...and so on...]
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I'm a bit late here, but you were almost there with question 2! In the manual for dnsmasq which you linked is an option called `--log-queries`. So simply:

```
$ echo "log-queries" > /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/log-queries
$ systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Then you should see logs similar to:

```
$ journalctl -f
Jan 21 15:39:15 computor dnsmasq[12345]: query[A] github.com from 127.0.0.1
Jan 21 15:39:15 computor dnsmasq[12345]: forwarded github.com to 8.8.8.8
Jan 21 15:39:15 computor dnsmasq[12345]: forwarded github.com to 8.8.4.4
Jan 21 15:39:15 computor dnsmasq[12345]: reply github.com is 140.82.118.4
```

*(I am running Debian rather than Ubuntu but I expect this will work the same.)*

---

When we come back to your original problem though, I think the logical way to make this work is adding these host definitions to your `/etc/hosts` and forcing NetworkManager's dnsmasq to use them (see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1191141/28965) or [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/117899/28965)). That is where I would expect to find local server definitions rather than digging around in `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/*`.