# Hotspot with dnsmasq to resolve local hosts

Tags: network-manager, 17.10, hot-spot, dnsmasq

I have a Hotspot configured to share my wired Internet connection with other devices, the hotspot is started using `nmcli con up Hotspot ifname virtual`.

The hostspot is up and use the IP `10.42.0.1`

At this point all works fine, any device can connect to the hotspot and use the internet.

Now I'm trying to setup `dnsmasq` to access to some virtual hosts in my computer from my phone, but when try to start the service I got the following error:

`dnsmasq[1034]: failed to create listening socket for 10.42.0.1: Address already in use`

I can see "some" process already listening on port 53

```
netstat -anlp | grep LISTEN | grep 10.42.0.1:53
tcp        0      0 10.42.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

The hotspot is launching some dns server?, can disable this to use `dnsmasq` or at least configure to read hosts from `/etc/hosts`?

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution:

Firstly remove any change made in the dnsmasq config file.

Create the following file `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq-shared.d/hosts.conf`

with:

```
address=/.local/10.42.0.1
```

Where `.local` is the last part of all my virtual domains in `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1    somedomain.local
127.0.0.1    another.domain.local
```

Restart the network manager and works like a charm.

> Apparently the network manager run his own dnsmasq.

The following links gave me an idea:

[Configure NetworkManager's dnsmasq to use /etc/hosts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117899/configure-networkmanagers-dnsmasq-to-use-etc-hosts)

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/dnsmasq.8.html